Synology Directory Server : Granting Access to a Former Employee's Files on Multiple Computers
I have a local network of computers running Windows, and user logins are managed through Synology Directory Server. One of the employees has left the company, and their work-related files, which are stored across multiple computers (not on a Synology NAS), are now inaccessible. I need to ensure that all the files created by the former employee are accessible to another user on the network.
What is the best way to transfer access or ownership of these files to another user across all computers? Is there an efficient method to change permissions or ownership remotely, or do I need to manually adjust settings on each machine?
